# Tengo que hacer un recorrido por un arreglo y guardar ciertos registros

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript

Buenas tardes a todos!

Quería saber si me podían ayudar con el siguiente problema...

Actualmente, en mi pantalla, tengo un **select** y cada vez que se escoge una opción del mismo se activa la siguiente función:

```
negocioOnChange(negocioSelected: Negocio) {
    if (negocioSelected && negocioSelected.id) {
        this.criteria.tipoSubcentroID = negocioSelected.id;
        console.log(this.criteria.tipoSubcentroID);
        this.subcentroService.getSubcentrosPorTipos(negocioSelected.id).subscribe((res: QueryResultsModel) => {
            this.subcentrosItems = res.items;
            console.log(this.subcentrosItems);
            let subcentrosList = this.subcentrosItems.find((e) => this.criteria.tipoSubcentroID == e.tipoSubcentroID);
            this.dataTable = subcentrosList;
            console.log(this.dataTable);
        });
    }
}
```

El **subcentrosItems** me recupera un array de distintos registros. Lo que yo necesito es guardar en **subcentrosList** un array con aquellos registros donde uno de sus valores coincida con this.criteria.tipoSubcentroID.

Espero puedan ayudarme! Y espero se haya entendido mi consulta! Muchas gracias. Espero su respuesta!

PD: Estoy trabajando con Angular y TS

Comment: Hola amigo, aca te dejo un ejemplo puedes hacer `.pipe()` en tu observable para tener un codigo mas sincrono y que tu respuesta sea mas directa y la operacion de filtrado se haga mas facil aca un [ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ruzrhg?file=src/app/app.component.ts), espero que te pueda servir.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

podria ser algo asi?

```
subcentrosItems.forEach(el => {
      if(el === this.criteria.tipoSubcentroID){
        subcentrosList.push(el)
      }
      
    });
```

el script de arriba toma el array subcentrosItems y si el criterio de busqueda coincide va a meter ese item al array, con lo cual puedes terminar con un array de x elementos o un array vacio si no se encontro el criterio.
Una vez terminado el foreach lo que puedes hacer es un consolelog de cierto indice (0,1,2,etc) o recorrer el array con otro foreach para que te imprima por consola cada item, como se ve abajo:

```
subcentrosItems.forEach(el => {
      if(el === this.criteria.tipoSubcentroID){
        subcentrosList.push(el)
      }      
    });

    console.log(subcentrosList[indiceItem]);

    subcentrosItems.forEach(el => console.log(el));
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir detalles a tu respuesta explicando porqué es una solución? Esto le será de ayuda a los demás visitantes del sitio, incluyendo al que formula la pregunta.

Comment: @FranAcuna por lo general trato de explicar mis respuestas, lo que sucede es que en este caso ni siquiera estoy seguro que funcione ya que el que formula la pregunta tampoco pone todo el codigo, y tampoco es que yo sea un experto, si al consultante le funcionase gustosamente explicare el script, esperemos a que el lo confirme y editare la respuesta

Comment: @HernánGarcia Me sirvió para poder encontrar todos aquellos que coincidan con el this.criteria.tipoSubcentroID... Solo que al hacer el push, no me figura nada en un console.log. Gracias!

Comment: @Gianfranco Grigera fijate si ahora te sirve

Comment: @HernánGarcia perfecto! Eso me sirvió correctamente. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!